# Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'AngularFireDatabase'?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

While hovering on collection I am getting this error

**Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'AngularFireDatabase'**

[image]

```
this.db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
      name: "Los Angeles",
      state: "CA",
      country: "USA"
  })
  .then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
```

I have already imported this

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "@angular/fire/database";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine , actually firestore is not available in firebase package we have to import it again .

```
//Use one which works fine for you 

import * as firebase from "firebase/app"; 
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

//Now import this 
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

For Angular Fire database we have to create an object of Angular Fire Database

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
```

If you are using Real Time Database then you have to do injection in constructor same way I was doing in above mentioned snap . So actually I was doing it in wrong way

[This](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/182) github post was helpful