# Cant load Game from ID

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error message:

```
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {
  pickCardAnimation = false;
  currentCard: string = '';
  game: Game;

  constructor(@Inject(Firestore) private firestore: Firestore, private route: ActivatedRoute, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newGame();
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log('id:', params['id']);  // Access 'id' using bracket notation

      this
        .firestore
        .collection('games')
        .doc(params['id'])
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((game) => {
          console.log('game update', game);
        });
    })
  }

  async newGame() {
    this.game = new Game();
  }
```

Error: src/app/game/game.component.ts:28:10 - error TS2339: Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore'.

28         .collection('games')

I want to load game from fire database with game id

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StartScreenComponent },
  { path: 'game/:id', component: GameComponent }
];
```

Comment: What are you passing to the constructor of GameComponent?  Whatever it is, it doesn't have a method called `collection` as the error message says.  We can't see what it is.

Comment: Possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547659/property-collection-does-not-exist-on-type-angularfiredatabase

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to be a game. Apparently the syntax has changed so much that I can't get anywhere with the tutorial video.